# How do I implement the VirtualFileSystem required by SharpZipLib.Portable?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, sharpziplib

I would like to add the [SharpZipLib.Portable](https://github.com/ygrenier/SharpZipLib.Portable) library to my `Xamarin.Forms` PCL project.  I am targeting Android and iOS.  The documentation mentions that you must implement a `VirtualFileSystem` in order to use the library, but I do not know how to do that and I have been unable to find much information on this topic.

Has anyone used this library that can guide me in the steps required to use it?

Answer (score 13):

I ended up here when trying to implement the [SharpZipLib.Portable](https://github.com/ygrenier/SharpZipLib.Portable).
I start using it without the `IVirtualFileSystem` because i had already a library called ([PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage)) that knows how to read and write in filesystem (tested it on `iOS` and `Android`).

**NOTE**: This implementations are all inside a PCL targeting `iOS`, `Android`. No specific code for Android or iOS are needed.

Here is a simple example how to extract a Zip file using `PCLStorage` and `SharpZipLib.Portable`:

```
public async void DonwLoadAndStoreZipFile()
{
    var bytes = await DownloadImageAsync("https://github.com/fluidicon.png");

    // IFolder interface comes from PCLStorage    
    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("zipFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("test.zip" , CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    using (Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        using (var zf = new ZipFile(stream))
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zf) 
            {                
                // Gete Entry Stream.
                Stream zipEntryStream = zf.GetInputStream(zipEntry);

                // Create the file in filesystem and copy entry stream to it.
                IFile zipEntryFile = await rootFolder.CreateFileAsync(zipEntry.Name , CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
                using(Stream outPutFileStream = await zipEntryFile.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
                {
                    await zipEntryStream.CopyToAsync(outPutFileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }                    
}
```

If you want to get some examples on how to use the `SharpZipLib.Portable` you can read here (original [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib)):
[Code reference](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Code-Reference) 
and
[Zip samples](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples).

**ALTERNATIVE:**

After doing what i explained above I ended up with a much simpler solution because i only needed to support ZIP files.
I used `ZipArchive Class` present in `System.IO.Compression` and `PCLStorage`, so with this solution i don't used `SharpZipLib.Portable`.

Here is the version:

```
public async void DonwLoadAndStoreZipFile()
{
    var bytes = await DownloadImageAsync(https://github.com/fluidicon.png);

    // IFolder interface comes from PCLStorage
    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("zipFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("test.zip" , CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    using (Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        using(ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                IFile zipEntryFile = await rootFolder.CreateFileAsync(entry.Name, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
                using (Stream outPutStream = await zipEntryFile.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
                {
                    await entry.Open().CopyToAsync(outPutStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Install SharpZipLib.Portable for PCL project only
2. Code to use it:

   ```
   using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core;
   using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

   public void ExtractZipFile(string archivePath, string password, string outFolder) {

       using(Stream fsInput = File.OpenRead(archivePath)) 
       using(zf = new ZipFile(fs)){

       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
           zf.Password = password;
       }

       foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zf) {
           if (!zipEntry.IsFile) {
               continue;
           }
           String entryFileName = zipEntry.Name;

           var fullZipToPath = Path.Combine(outFolder, entryFileName);
           var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullZipToPath);
           if (directoryName.Length > 0) {
               Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
           }

           var buffer = new byte[4096];

           using(var zipStream = zf.GetInputStream(zipEntry))
           using (Stream fsOutput = File.Create(fullZipToPath)) {
               StreamUtils.Copy(zipStream, fsOutput , buffer);
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```